# Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I have a getS3Object function to get (json) objects located in aws s3

```
object client_connect extends Serializable {
      
      val s3_get_path = "/dbfs/mnt/s3response"  
      
      def getS3Objects(s3ObjectName: String, s3Client: AmazonS3): String = {
          val objectKey = s"${s3ObjectName}"
          val inputS3Stream = s3Client.getObject("myS3Bucket", objectKey).getObjectContent
          val inputS3String = IOUtils.toString(inputS3Stream, "UTF-8")
          val filePath = s"${s3_get_path}/${objectKey}"
          val file = new File(filePath)
          val fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)
          val bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)
          bw.write(inputS3String)
          bw.close()
          fileWriter.close()
          inputS3String
      } 
    }
```

Messages are ingested using a streaming framework

The source streaming dataframe 'source_df' which reads from azure event hub looks like below

| body |
| --- |
| 8c44f2715ab81c16ecb31d527e18465d.json~2021-05-26~13-14-56~OH |
| a4f9e914c1a40e5828b0eb129b1234b2.json~2022=05-09~15-12-22~MI |

The 'body' column contains string values delimited by ‘~’ where the first element is the object id that is passed as a parameter into the getS3Object function

The second parameter to this function is the S3client used to connect to aws S3 which is defined inside a serializable class.

```
final class s3clientBuild() extends  Serializable {
 def s3connection(AccessKey: String, SecretKey: String) = {
 val clientRegion: Regions = Regions.US_EAST_1
 val creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey)
 AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
 .withRegion(clientRegion)
 .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
 .build()  
 }
}


val AccessKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Scope", key = "AccessKey-ID")
val SecretKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Scope", key = "AccessKey-Secret")
```

Write Stream:-

```
val streamWriter = source_df 
  .writeStream
  .queryName("Write_stream")
  .option("checkpointLocation", chk_pt)
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(3 seconds))
  .outputMode("append")
  .foreachBatch(
  (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => Try {
      batchDF.persist()

        val object_df = batchDF.select(split(col("body"), "~").getItem(0).as("ObjectID"))

        val df_response =  object_df.repartition(2).mapPartitions(iterator => {
          val api_connect  = new s3clientBuild()
          val s3client = api_connect.s3connection(AccessKey, SecretKey)
          val resp = iterator.map(row => {
           val name = cli_connector.getS3Objects(row.getString(0), s3client) 
            (name)
            })
          resp
        }).toDF("value").select(from_json($"value".cast("string"), MySchema) as "fields").select($"fields.*")
        
        df_response.count()
        
    batchDF.unpersist()
  } match {
    case Success(_) =>
    case Failure(e) => {throw e}
  } 
  )
```

However I get the below error message:-

```
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter, value: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@1f1c5f4f)
    - field (class: $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: sensorwriter_0526, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter)
    - object (class $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@41c5f54f)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125/$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$sensorwriter_0526$3:(L$lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125/$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$9965/578518190, $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$9965/578518190@29101ed3)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, name: func, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, MapPartitions $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$9965/578518190@29101ed3, obj#51280: java.lang.String
+- DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(TripID#51276.toString, StructField(TripID,StringType,true)), obj#51279: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
   +- ShuffleQueryStage 0, Statistics(sizeInBytes=384.0 B, rowCount=8, isRuntime=true)
      +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(2), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [id=#9176]
         +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
            +- FileScan parquet [TripID#51276] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[dbfs:/mnt/pp-telematics-working-2/Sensor/test_micro], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<TripID:string>
)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/execution/MapPartitionsExec.$anonfun$doExecute$3:(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/MapPartitionsExec;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$Lambda$9859/1700433546, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$Lambda$9859/1700433546@4b5380b3)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function3.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted:(Lscala/Function1;Lorg/apache/spark/TaskContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lorg/apache/spark/TaskContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$7220/2013256266, org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$7220/2013256266@2a2fa8fb)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, name: f, type: interface scala.Function3)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[741] at start at command-2364010639414209:1)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: _rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@2bae52d5)
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@1da88b1b)
    - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@2bae52d5))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[742] at start at command-2364010639414209:1)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: _rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@599070d7)
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@4dff1ebc)
    - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@599070d7))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[743] at start at command-2364010639414209:1)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (MapPartitionsRDD[743] at start at command-2364010639414209:1,org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency@6508edf9))
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2931)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2925)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2925)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1806)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleMapStageSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1473)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3146)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3134)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3122)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter, value: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@1f1c5f4f)
    - field (class: $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: sensorwriter_0526, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter)
    - object (class $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@41c5f54f)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125/$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$sensorwriter_0526$3:(L$lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125/$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$9965/578518190, $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$9965/578518190@29101ed3)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, name: func, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, MapPartitions $lineeabf6de089d548a29e8a43ad48edbc49125.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$9965/578518190@29101ed3, obj#51280: java.lang.String
+- DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(TripID#51276.toString, StructField(TripID,StringType,true)), obj#51279: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
   +- ShuffleQueryStage 0, Statistics(sizeInBytes=384.0 B, rowCount=8, isRuntime=true)
      +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(2), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [id=#9176]
         +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
            +- FileScan parquet [TripID#51276] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[dbfs:/mnt/pp-telematics-working-2/Sensor/test_micro], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<TripID:string>
)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/execution/MapPartitionsExec.$anonfun$doExecute$3:(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/MapPartitionsExec;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$Lambda$9859/1700433546, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$Lambda$9859/1700433546@4b5380b3)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function3.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted:(Lscala/Function1;Lorg/apache/spark/TaskContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lorg/apache/spark/TaskContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$7220/2013256266, org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$Lambda$7220/2013256266@2a2fa8fb)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, name: f, type: interface scala.Function3)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[741] at start at command-2364010639414209:1)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: _rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@2bae52d5)
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@1da88b1b)
    - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@2bae52d5))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[742] at start at command-2364010639414209:1)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: _rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@599070d7)
    - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@4dff1ebc)
    - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@599070d7))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[743] at start at command-2364010639414209:1)
    - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.Tuple2, (MapPartitionsRDD[743] at start at command-2364010639414209:1,org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency@6508edf9))
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1791)
    ... 6 more
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some information but I assume I know the answer:

If the constants you are using in the lambda passed to `mapPartitions` (`AccessKey` and `SecretKey`) reside in an object (or class) which is not serializable, this issue can occur.

Spark can't serialize independent values, so it serializes the containing object. My guess, is the object containing these values also contains some value of type `DataStreamWriter` which prevents it from being serializable.

Make sure all of the constants reside in a separate object and access them via `MyObject.MyConst` and you should be good to go.